# Migrating Users onto same app but different backend/server bec of Parse migration

Tags: database, parse-platform

I am migrating my existing deployed App from Parse to another server. There are about 1k users already logged onto the existing app. How can I smoothly get them on the new app (with new UI anddifferent backend) without making them login again with a new/same password? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far. Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand, but if you want to migrate your parse database to another server without downtime it's simple :

Prepare your server (a lot of solutions exist : [Mlab](http://docs.mlab.com/migrating-from-parse/#choosing-a-plan), [AWS](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk))

When your mongoDB is ready, get your mongodb url :
`mongodb://MONGO_USER:PASSWORD@52.51.73.48:27017/parse`

and go to parse dashboard -> Your App -> App settings -> general -> Migrate Database (somethink like that) and specify your mongoDB url

Parse copy the database and start to use your database instead the Parse database. No downtime, no data changed, no client config changes.

After this operation, you have all your time for migrate the parse api to your own server.